# Problems with boost::multi_index, incomplete type, no matching function call, etc

Tags: c++, boost, containers, multi-index, boost-multi-index

This is with Boost 1.72.0. What am I doing wrong? This is a simple example where I'm trying to create a struct named employee, which can be sorted by both id and name. I wanted to try this out before integrating multi_index into a larger more complex project, which requires a lot more indices. But I ran into errors using the code below. I compiled it using GCC 7.30. Since the error messages are complex and verbose, I left them off.

Here is the full source of the minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>

using namespace boost::multi_index;

struct employee {
    employee(unsigned int id, std::string name)
        : id(id), name(name)
    {}

    unsigned int id;
    std::string name;

    bool operator<(const employee& other) const noexcept {
        return this->id < other.id;
    }
};

struct indexedById {};
struct indexedByName {};

using EmployeeContainer = boost::multi_index_container
<
    employee,
    indexed_by<
        ordered_unique<tag<indexedById>, identity<employee>>,
        hashed_non_unique<tag<indexedByName>, member<employee, std::string, &employee::name>>
    >
>;

int main()
{
    EmployeeContainer mi;
    auto& inserter = mi.get<indexedByName>();
    inserter.emplace(0, "uber duber");
    inserter.emplace(1,  "gotcha");
    inserter.emplace(3, "dang");

    for(auto& it : mi.get<indexedById>())
        std::cout << it.id << ": " << it.name << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I fixed it. I needed to include the header files  and  in addition to the others.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/key_extractors.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>

using namespace boost::multi_index;

struct employee {
    employee(unsigned int id, std::string name)
        : id(id), name(name)
    {}

    unsigned int id;
    std::string name;

    bool operator<(const employee& other) const noexcept {
        return this->id < other.id;
    }
};

struct indexedById {};
struct indexedByName {};

using EmployeeContainer = boost::multi_index_container
<
    employee,
    indexed_by<
        ordered_unique<tag<indexedById>, identity<employee>>,
        hashed_non_unique<tag<indexedByName>, member<employee, std::string, &employee::name>>
    >
>;

int main()
{
    EmployeeContainer mi;
    auto& inserter = mi.get<indexedByName>();
    inserter.emplace(0, "uber duber");
    inserter.emplace(1, "gotcha");
    inserter.emplace(3, "dang");

    for(auto& it : mi.get<indexedById>())
        std::cout << it.id << ": " << it.name << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

```
0: uber duber
1: gotcha
3: dang
```

So, moral of the story, add header files for each type of index you're doing!